# WPF Current time without using dispatcher

Tags: wpf, time, dispatchertimer

I'd like to know is there any other option to show current time without using DispatcherTimer?
Unfortunately app need's to run in slow PC's and DispatcherTimer continuously increasing memory usage. I check that in WPF Performance Profiling Tool and that's true - CPU usage with 1sec timespan is ~5-15%.
And becouse im using class to get time value and show that on label, it would be great if method to show could run without xaml-generated controls.

Thanks!

@EDIT:

```
DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer(); 
dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick); 
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0); 
dispatcherTimer.Start();
```

and when tick:

```
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
lbl.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString("F"); 
// lbl is static label which i create once and show i several windows. 
}
```

Comment: Oo - can you show us the implementation of the `DispatcherTimer`. Normally, I wouldn't expect the memory to grow. So let's have a look, if you have produced a memory leak. ;o)

Comment: You need to "get" the current time someway. Whether it's wrapped in a helper or out-of-box. I'd guess if there's a noticable performance blip in your run-time, your doing something weird with your `Timer`.

Comment: First of all - is "Dispatcher Invoke" in WPF Performance Tol means running DispatcherTimer ? I think so, becouse when i commend that code, its now like 0 to 1-2 % (test for 10 min).

Comment: Well i guess i missundersood Dispatcher Invoke and DispatcherTimer..

Answer (score 4):

Your interval is zero, meaning...ouch. Why is it necessary to update the UI more than 10 times a second? No human being will be able to process the changes if they are that frequent. By default WPF only updates the screen 60 times a second, so your interval should be at least 1000/60 = 16.6 ms. However, I'd argue that something as high as 250ms could be good enough.